# how to remove django from ubuntu?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I have installed Django from setup.py from my home directory.
I would like to uninstall it.
Please tell me a working method.

P.S-

1. I have seen most of the answers in Stackoverflow but they did not work.
   Using ubuntu 12.04.
2. One Solution in Stackoverflow for MAC OS X did work for my MAC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

make sure you install django and other python packages on [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) next time, if you do, it will be as simple as deleting a directory.

Answer (score 22):

1. Install python-pip

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-pip
   ```
2. Remove django using pip

   ```
   sudo pip uninstall Django
   ```
3. Uninstall python-pip

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove python-pip
   ```

Answer (score 9):

```
Open the python shell

>> import django

>> django.__path__
```

Copy the path. then press Ctrl +D

Execute following Command on the shell:

```
sudo  rm -r path
```

or from terminal:

```
pip uninstall Django
```